# Regex to exclude string at beginning of string

Tags: .net, regex

I want to exclude a fixed string at the beginning, so that I only get the numbers after the fixed string.

The fixed string is RE163, so here are some examples with the expected result:

```
Example     Result
RE16310000  10000
RE16312345  12345
RE16316300  16300
```

I've already tried the following regex:

It works for these examples:

```
RE16310000  10000
RE16319999  19999
```

But doesn't fit for that:

```
RE16320000  320000    (Expected 20000)
RE16316320  320       (Expected 16320)
```

Comment: *I've already tried the following regex*. I can't see any regex!

Comment: Why not just do `myString = myString.Remove("RE163")`?

Comment: I added a .NET tag  as the regex solution should work for .NET regex flavor.

Comment: Does Dmitry's solution work? If not, try `(?<=RE163)[0-9]+`

Answer (score 4):

Why *regex*? Just `Substring` is enough:

```
string source = "RE16310000";

string result = source.Substring(5);
```

In case you *have to use* regular expressions you can try

```
(?<=RE163)[0-9]+$
```

pattern; C# example:

```
string pattern = @"(?<=RE163)[0-9]+$";

string result = Regex.Match(source, pattern).Value;
```

Comment: sorry, it's for an electronic file format. So I can't use C# only regex to filter a line

Comment: @Lou: In case you have to use regular expressions the patter can be `(?<=RE163).+$`

Answer (score 1):

Try the following regex `^(?:RE163)(\d*)`

- ^ is for start of line
- ?: is a non capturing group
- (?:RE163) ignores the first 5 letters and numbers you don't want
- (\d*) is the group that captures the numbers you want